# How to configure default name for authentication app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm an newbee to Asp.NET Core identity.
Have made an application with identity adn MFA enabled. When sign-in with my authentication app i see an default name: Microsoft.AspNet.Core.Identity.UI and below that my accountname. [Example name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MVqV.png)
How to configure or were can i change this in Asp.NET Core application to for example the app name?

Have looked for anwsers in Stackoverflow and another sites.

Comment: First, please share your MFA code so we can more accurately diagnose. Take a look at the docs under the section "Change the site name in the QR code" and remove/readd the MFA QR code to your authenticator app - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thx for your comment, Adding my code is not nessecary anymore because i found the solution in the  link you added in your comment underneath "Change the site name in QR code"  Thanks again